# Calculation showing wrong result

Tags: postgresql, performance, coalesce, postgresql-performance

I am using postgresql to display QA% in my project. Now issue is that, QA% for one of the user is showing wrong data.

this is my calculation I am using to show QA%

```
(to_char(( (coalesce(s_qa_num,0) + coalesce(s_qa_num_adtl,0))/nullif(coalesce(s_qa_den,0) + coalesce(s_qa_den_adtl,0),0))*100,'999D99')||'%')::character varying as qa_pct
```

Output from the view I have created

https://pastiebin.com/5db2d1589ef6b

the view I am using for this

https://pastiebin.com/5db2d1cb48822

the query I run in pgadmin

```
select * from mystats_in_eligbility.vw_m_quality where empl_id = '329509' 
AND dte BETWEEN '2019-03-23' AND '2019-09-06'
order by dte desc;
```

Current result for QA% is 97.53%
expected result is 96.34%.

Comment: Let me suggest to use some on-line fiddle like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11) Create the table and add inserts with your sample data.

Comment: Your pastbin is difficult to interpret. As @McNets suggests - we need sample tables (`CREATE TABLE blah...`) and data (`INSERT INTO blah VALUES...`). And please give us the **full** SQL statement - context is important! I have a few articles on how to ask questions here on my profile - you might want to take a look? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: @McNets I have updated

Comment: @Vérace please check updated question

Comment: There's no data (`INSERT INTO`) for us to look at to check the validity of the calculation. Furthermore, you have `)||'%')::character` but a search of both pastebins for the `%` character gives nothing so I'm wondering where it is? Your query is very large and it would appear to be very tricky to zone in on your QA% problem - is there any way you could produce a **Minimum**, Complete Verifiable Example?

Answer (score 1):

I built a fiddle with your initial data ... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ab139/1

@Verace the '%' is added to the result to make it appear a percentage number

still I don't get your result ... I assume you create the arithmetic middle of your QA - because with your query I still get one row per day..

```
SELECT ( 
    to_char( 
        ( ( (
          SUM( s_qa_num) / SUM (s_qa_den) 
         )*100)
      ),'999D99')||'%')::character varying as qa_pct FROM t;
```

this far easier Select produces your desired result ...

still your view in pastebin seems to lack some lines - as your select includes data from late march to september, your pastebin starts in early april

Comment: And why put the `%` into the string  in the SQL? That's a client issue. It really messes up the SQL!

Comment: I see it from the same point